# Get Unique Google Home user id/ device Id in Dialogflow Fullfillment Hook

Tags: node.js, webhooks, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

We need to associate our room number with different google home device.
So we need an unique id on the dialogflow fullfillment Hook.
I need an unique device / user id. is there any api for getting imei or mac address.??

Can 
We are tried the account linking and we got user id, but some time it refreshes, We are getting below response.

```
{
    "originalDetectIntentRequest": {
        "source": "google",
        "version": "2",
        "payload": {
          "surface": {
            "capabilities": [
              {
                "name": "actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO"
              },
              {
                "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
              }
            ]
          },
          "inputs": [
            {
              "rawInputs": [
                {
                  "query": "one",
                  "inputType": "VOICE"
                }
              ],
              "arguments": [
                {
                  "rawText": "one",
                  "textValue": "one",
                  "name": "text"
                }
              ],
              "intent": "actions.intent.TEXT"
            }
          ],
          "user": {
            "lastSeen": "2018-10-26T12:19:26Z",
            "locale": "en-SG",
            "userId": "15405557729312087450498"
          },
          "conversation": {
            "conversationId": "ABwppHGPccKMD31_LlOcGGo9CWCtitXeXiZBedpNhqU0L-uc1uCdT8gsFGPeb3WKa6jCguq1gIaoHCcbdp2lqr8",
            "type": "ACTIVE",
            "conversationToken": "[\"actions_capability_audio_output\",\"actions_capability_media_response_audio\",\"fdd1b5e2-b11a-43d2-ac6d-eb92b3713792_id_dialog_context\",\"google_assistant_input_type_voice\",\"room_service_-_yes_dialog_context\",\"room_service_-_yes_dialog_params_order_quantity2\",\"roomservice-followup\"]"
          },
          "availableSurfaces": [
            {
              "capabilities": [
                {
                  "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
                },
                {
                  "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER"
                },
                {
                  "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get a unique device ID, MAC address, IMEI, IP address, or anything similar.

The best you can do is to setup account linking. And keep in mind that users may choose to unlink their accounts or access the service "anonymously".